# tokenizing lines with unequal spacing between the words

Tags: java

I have a file with couple lines as follow:

```
BEULAH         0.048 69.577    360
ANTOINETTE     0.048 69.625    361
CANDICE        0.046 69.671    362
JUANA          0.046 69.717    363
```

and I want to read the firs 2  in java: like BEULAH  and  0.048

Here is my code to reading line by line:

```
    BufferedReader brF = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileNameF));     
    String line = null;
    while ((line = brF.readLine()) != null) {

    }
```

But when it comes to tokenizing the spaces between words are not the same. I am wondering what is the best way to do so?( I know one way is o manually change the spaceing in the file but not a clever idea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If space is your delimiter then you can just use a regex to do the splitting.

```
BufferedReader brF = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileNameF));     
String line = null;
while ((line = brF.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+"); //Splits for one or more space.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the line formating is the same meaning that `String` is followed by `Double`, I would suggest to use the `Scanner`

```
BufferedReader brF = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileNameF));     
String line = null;
Scanner scanner;
while ((line = brF.readLine()) != null) {
   scanner = new Scanner(line);
   scanner.next(); //Will return the string
   scanner.nexDouble(); //Will return following double value
}
```

Comment: FYI Scanner's are slower than split. And scanners are slower than BufferedReader. Avoid scanners if you can, do everything manually :)